# Composite PK with Lazy Loading does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am slowly but steadly moving to despair .. I have a simple case of a join/relation table with composite key and trying to get one entity with the join table information, but for the rest I am looking for lazy loading. Here it comes:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipes` ( `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredients` ( `recipe_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, `ingredient_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,`amount` INT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`recipe_id`,`ingredient_id`);   
CREATE TABLE `ingredients` (  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,`name` longtext NOT NULL );
```

The FK constraints are omitted for lengths sake.
Now in the code I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipes")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "recipe",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Set<RecipeIngredient> ingredients = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
}
```

Ingredient Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ingredients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ingredient", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<RecipeIngredient> recipes = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
}
```

RecipeIngredientId:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class RecipeIngredientId implements  Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Recipe recipe;

    private Ingredient ingredient;
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }
        RecipeIngredientId that = (RecipeIngredientId) o;
        return Objects.equals( ingredient.getId(), that.ingredient.getId() ) &&
                Objects.equals( recipe.getId(), that.recipe.getId() );
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash( recipe.getId(), ingredient.getId() );
    }
    
    
    public RecipeIngredientId(Recipe recipe2, Ingredient ingredient2) {
        this.recipe = recipe2;
        this.ingredient = ingredient2;
    }
    
    
}
```

And finally the cross table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipe_ingredients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(RecipeIngredientId.class)
public class RecipeIngredient implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Recipe recipe;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Ingredient ingredient;
    
    private int amount;
}
```

In RecipeRepositoryImpl:

```
        
        TypedQuery<Object> query = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Recipe r  LEFT JOIN   r.ingredients ri"
                + " WHERE r.id= :id", Object.class);
        
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return  query.getResultList();
```

Although I wildly put Lazy everywhere I could now , I am still getting all data  - the query to ingredients table is still performed EAGERLY. Namely:

```
    {
        "id": 1, "ingredients": [
            {
                "recipe": 1,
                "ingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Kartoffeln"
                    "recipes": [
                        {
                            "recipe": 1,
                            "ingredient": 1,
                            "amount": 100
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "amount": 100
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am expecting that Ingredients only includes Id field and not name and circular recipes list again ...
Thankful for any help!
Cheers, Nikki

Comment: `LAZY` does not mean 'do not load'. It means 'load when requested'. In this case, when you tell Jackson to serialize an entity, it tries to serialize all the properties (why shouldn't it?), hence *requesting* all the lazy properties to be loaded

Comment: If you want Jackson to detect which properties are lazy and refrain from serializing them, you can use [`Hibernate5Module`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-hibernate/javadoc/h5/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/hibernate5/Hibernate5Module.Feature.html). IMO such an approach is a code smell, though (either the client of your API needs a certain piece of information or it doesn't, why should switching between eager/lazy loading suddenly change the API contract?)

Comment: OK, I understand that something triggers getIngredient() method, but I wasnt able to stop it from doing so. I also that serialization of those fields is stopped with: @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
I understand your link is not much different from custom deserializer?

Comment: I managed to do this with Custom Serializer. Thank you for the hint!!